# How to add custom properties to HTTPS calls so I can see them in Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have a C# client application that calls a web application in Azure (also in written in C#, ASP .NET Core). Traffic gets captured in Azure Log Analytics so I can see it in Azure Application Insights.

When calling the web application from my client application, I would like to add some information about the version of the client application. I want this information to be easily viewable in Application Insights.

I notice that the **requests** table in Application Insights has a column called **customDimensions**. Maybe I can put stuff there, but I don't know how.

My idea is to add this information as a header and somehow configure the application to copy this information from the header into **customDimensions**. Is this a good way to go? If so, how do I accomplish the latter half (configure the application to copy this information from the header into **customDimensions**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a telemetry initializer for this, as explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer):

> Use telemetry initializers to enrich telemetry with additional information or to override telemetry properties set by the standard telemetry modules.

There is a base class ([TelemetryInitializerBase](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/main/NETCORE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/TelemetryInitializerBase.cs)) that you can use which provides access to the http context to get details of the headers:

```cs
public class CustomInitializer : TelemetryInitializerBase
{
    public CustomInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(contextAccessor)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(HttpContext platformContext, RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var appVersion = platformContext.Request.Headers["x-app-version"].ToString();
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appVersion))
            requestTelemetry.Properties["appVersion"] = appVersion;
    }
}
```

Add this initializer to the web app running in Azure. Then, in the customDimensions field of the request telemetry you can find the value of `appVersion`.

Another option is to set custom propertions in the controller action like this:

```cs
var appVersion = Request.Headers["x-app-version"].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appVersion))
{
    var requestTelemetry = HttpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
    requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("appVersion", appVersion);
}
```